# Trying to scrape a webpage to get all links but all the links got are the webpage's url itself

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch all the links in the following webpage https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br/fundsPage/7. As the webpage is full of javascript, I'm using requests-html library to execute them all.

My goal is to iterate through all the 18 pages to get all the funds' names and its corresponding links (which I intend to scraper later on), but I can't get the real links. The only link I get is https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br/fundsPage/7, the page's url itself, common to all elements. If I use a browser to access the page, I get redirected to a different webpage which has a different url.

Here is my code:

```
session = AsyncHTMLSession()

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Origin': 'https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br/',
    'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

base_site = 'https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br/fundsPage/7'

r1 = await session.get(base_site, headers=headers, verify=False)

# Getting all the links right before the the rendering to compare to the the answer rendered
divs = r1.html.find('div')
links = r1.html.find('a')
urls = r1.html.absolute_links

await r1.html.arender(wait=2)

new_divs = r1.html.find('div')
new_links = r1.html.find('a')
new_urls = r1.html.absolute_links

print('Divs before the rendering: {0} \nDivs after the rendering: {1}'.format(len(divs), len(new_divs)))
print('Links before the rendering: {0} \nLinks after the rendering: {1}'.format(len(links), len(new_links)))
print('URLs before the rendering: {0} \nURLs after the rendering: {1}'.format(len(urls), len(new_urls)))

i = 1
for l in r1.html.find('a'):
    if l.text != '' and '\n' not in l.text:
        print('Link of interest {0}: {1} {2}'.format(i, l.text, l.url))
        i += 1
```

The output is:

```
Link of interest 1: AF INVEST CRI FDO. INV. IMOB – RECEBÍVEIS IMOB. https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br/fundsPage/7
Link of interest 2: FII AFHI CRI https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br/fundsPage/7
Link of interest 3: AF INVEST FDO INV. IMOB. - RECEBÍVEIS IMOB. https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br/fundsPage/7
Link of interest 4: FII AFINVCR https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br/fundsPage/7
Link of interest 5: ALIANZA FOF FUNDO DE INVESTIMENTO IMOBILIÁRIO https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br/fundsPage/7
```

Any suggestion?